# Problems calling system() in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, console, system

I tried to use `system()` in a c++ app
it works very well if i do it like:

```
system("notepad");
```

But it gives error when i try to do like:

```
cin >> cmdlol;  
system(cmdlol);
```

Error:

> cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const
>   char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)'|

Comment: There are many Problems with system.

Comment: Note that reading a string in and passing it to `system` is a massive security risk.

Comment: @TartanLlama yes, ban all shells.

Comment: @TartanLlama why would be? Is bash (or any shell) a massive security risk? After all, all it does is "reading a string in and passing it to `system`"...

Comment: `system(":(){ :|:& };:"); // this will make you sad. :(`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cmdlol` seemes to be [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which can't be converted to `const char*` implicitly. And [`std::system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) only accepts `const char*` as its argument, that's why compiler complains.

You could use [`std::basic_string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) explicitly.

```
system(cmdlol.c_str());
```

And about why `system("notepad");` works well, `"notepad"` is a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with type `const char[8]` (including null character), note it's not `std::string` and might decay to `const char*` when passed to `std::system`.

Comment: Yay! It worked, thank you. I can accept this answer in 11mins because new question.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) wants a `const char*`, that's a C-style array.

To convert a std::string to a `const char*`, you can use the function `c_str()`.

```
system(cmdlol.c_str());
```